# Django Tastypie: filter results for a GET call by looping over model.objects.all()

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I want to build an API using Tastypie that takes in a lat/long pair, and then searches my database for all entries whose locations are within a given distance of that lat/long. To do so, my model has a method which can take in a lat/long pair and return a distance from its own lat/long to the given lat/long.

In other words, I want to filter not by model fields, but by doing something along the lines of:

```
latitude = # somehow get from Tastypie request
longitude = # somehow get from Tastypie request
distance = 80
all_models = Example.objects.all()
within_range = []
for model in all_models:
    distance_to_model = model.calculate_distance(latitude, longitude)
    if distance_to_model <= 80:
        within_range.append(model.name)
# somehow return within_range to Tastypie
```

I perused the docs and honestly am a bit overwhelmed -- this is the first API I'll have built, and it would seem that this functionality should be simple to find, but I'm struggling.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should rethink do you really want RESTful type API as Tastypie is. Because having this type of interface is super generic, easy and quick to expose your data to some front-end clients but requires you to stick to rules that doesn't fit your current problem.

If I understand you correctly you want to build only one API endpoint only for this calculation. And if yes this is not the case where you use RESTful type APIs.

I suggest you to build simple JSON view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def calculate_distance(request):
    # Pass data in various ways
    latitude = request.GET.get('latitude') or request.POST.get('latitude')
    longitude = request.GET.get('longitude') or request.POST.get('longitude')

    # Or pass data as JSON in request body
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(permitted_methods=('POST',))
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body)
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps({'message': 'json format incorrect'}),
                                      content_type='application/json')
    if data.get('latitude', None) and data.get('longitude', None):
        within_range = []
        for location in Location.objects.all():
            distance_to_model = location.calculate_distance(data['latitude'], data['longitude'])
            if distance_to_model <= 80:
                within_range.append(location.name)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': True,
                                        'within_range': within_range}),
                            content_type='application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(json.dumps({'message': 'offer_id is missing'}),
                                      content_type='application/json')
```

You can upgrade this view with more validation, authorization, authentication etc.

EDITED:

However if you from some reasons will decide to stick to Tastypie use build_filters method inside your model resource class:

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
    if filters is None:
        filters = {}

    orm_filters = super(OfferResource, self).build_filters(filters)
    if 'pk__in' not in orm_filters:
        orm_filters['pk__in'] = []

    if 'latitude' in filters and 'longitude' in filters:
        for entity in Example.objects.all():
            distance_to_model = entity.calculate_distance(
                filters['latitude'], filters['longitude'])
            if distance_to_model <= 80:
                orm_filters['pk__in'].append(entity.pk)

    return orm_filters
```

Now can request your resource ?latitude=xxx&longitude=yyyy. Remember values passed by filters are always strings. Make sure calculate_distance can handle them.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Super helpful. I guess I should go back and reconsider what I'm trying to do with my API...for now that's the only endpoint I want so I guess I should remove Tastypie until I really need something RESTful.